Writing privacy policy
On my Wordpress site which is basically a news site, I have no forms that i collect info. No registration, no commenting, no contact form... All that is "collected" from users are automatic default stuff that I don't know about, that whatever my host does which i guess get logged in server logs. What do I need to say in privacy policy about it - specifically I ask about the IP address. Is it considered personal info? The IPs of users are tracked by analytics sites etc... For example I had Statcounter on one of my sites before and it writes the IP and browser of user but I am not doing anything whatsoever with it. What needs to be said about IP address in privacy policy?
